# Cannot get to install screen via USB - Surface Pro 4

Tags: boot, dual-boot, grub2, partitioning, usb

I was previously able to install and get Ubuntu 16.04 up and running via USB stick.  After using it for a week I decided to do a factory reset of windows 10 and re-partition to allow me to allocate more space to Ubuntu and create a more practical partition layout.

Factory reset went fine, installed Ubuntu.  Ubuntu would not load from hard drive.  Attempted to repair boot from within live session.  Windows/Ubuntu would not load after this and took many tries to get the system restored.

Now, factory SP4 image installed.  All updates done (essentially where I started at the beginning of this whole process).  I can no longer able to get to the install screen while trying to boot from USB.  Will just boot loop the black Surface screen and end up back at the UFEI screen.  Win10 boots fine from SSD.  The only difference I see is "Windows Boot Manager" is no longer on the boot configuration screen.  I have tried 3 different USB sticks (all worked previously) with no luck.  I have spent 10+ hours trying to research this and tried to make asking a question on here my absolute last resort.  I know how irritating redundant questions, or questions asked that are easily solved via search so I really home this doesn't fall into that category.  Thanks!

edit: fast boot/hibernate disabled.  Bitlocker disabled

Answer (score 0):

I was finally able to disable secure boot (I never had to disable this before).  My UEFI was freezing whenever I tried to make any changes, but after waiting 10 min or so then rebooting the settings finally stuck and I was able to boot the USB.  Hope this helps someone.